# Warning: exec() [function.exec]: Unable to fork on shared hosting

Tags: php

I have using shared hosting Go-daddy server 
I'm unable to run this command line on server

Warning: system() [function.system]: Unable to fork [ls -lart]

give me idea to run the script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648949/php-warning-exec-unable-to-fork

Comment: i am working on shared hosting server so that is not working on my server 
i also tried 
echo system("ulimit -a"); accepted answer but not working on server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shared hosting systems disable some commands for security reasons , you need to work around that , use native php for what you want to do, open the directory and read its content using php itself.

`system` and `exec` are usually completely disabled or partially limited.

if you are interested here is a simple code to get directory content :

```
if (is_dir($base) && is_readable($base)) {

    if ($handle = opendir($base)) {
        $base .= '/';
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            //$entry is a file or directory including `.` and `..`
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm working on to merging PDF files so you have any idea about this

Comment: that is a hole new question, get the list of pdf files with the code i have provided and then do what ever you want with them.
pdfmerger for php https://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/ or one of these : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794435/merge-pdf-files-with-php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404601/merging-pdf-files-with-php-fpdi